# yii add more textbox not saved in database

Tags: php, yii

In my view the form as

```
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" id="table-data" align="center" style="border:1px dashed #CCCCCC" class="table table-vcenter table-striped">
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td> % Completion</td>
    <td> <?php echo $form->textField($model_result,'floatPaymentpercentage[]',array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'%')); ?></td>
     <td> <?php echo $form->textField($model_result,'varAmount[]',array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Amount')); ?></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add btn btn-xs btn-warning"></td>
</tr>
```

Here i have two textboxes for payment terms..if i save ones it will be saved.

If i add more the last will not saved in database

In my controller we can use print_r()

```
echo ("<pre>"); print_r($_POST); echo ("</pre>");exit;
```

The default text field values only shown here.
 Here the text fields are added dynamically. 
The dynamic added text field's values are not displayed.

In my model the rules are

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(

        array('floatPaymentpercentage','required'),
        array('varAmount','required'),
    );
}
```

here is the java script for add more

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

        });


        $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
        if($(this).val() == "Add")
        {
        var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
         $tr.find('.tr_clone_add').val('Delete')// set value to Delet
        $tr.find('.tr_clone_add').val('Delete')// set value to Delet
        .toggleClass('tr_clone_add delete')// toggle classes
        .unbind('click'); // unbind the current events from button
        $tr.after($clone);
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 

        }
        });
                            </script>
```

Please help me to fix this.

Here i can add js for funuction add more
 Thanks

Comment: Show how you add more fields to this. Don't forget to prefix fields names with model name. Also model validation must be `CActiveForm::validateTabular($model_result)` to validate multiple entries of same attribute.